# React functional array delay to update

Tags: reactjs, react-state, react-map-gl

Helllo everyone, I have this issue where I am successfully sorting the array state of an object alphabetically using their cities but the problem is that the array that is getting visualized only updates after I search something on the UI.

I tried to look it up but still lost here is the video of what is happening
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17pAwTeo8IZ6mw3dd2pxDxbfY-ToL7cjG/view?usp=sharing

here is the code

[image: map where I visualize the list]

[image: sort function]

full code here

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./body.css";
import Axios from "axios";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";

function SearchBar() {
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  async function getUsers() {
    Axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((response) => {
        setFilteredData(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, []);

  function handleReset() {
    getUsers();

    setSearch("");
    handleClear();
  }

  const handleClear = () => {
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input")).forEach(
      (input) => (input.value = "")
    );
  };

  const delItem = (id) => {
    setFilteredData(filteredData.filter((e) => e.name.localeCompare(id) !== 0));
  };

  const sort = () => {
    setFilteredData(
      filteredData.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.address.city.localeCompare(b.address.city);
      })
    );
    // console.log(sorted);
    // setFilteredData(sorted);
    console.log(filteredData);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form class="search-bar">
        <input
          type="input"
          name="search"
          pattern=".*\S.*"
          // requiredw
          autoComplete="off"
          placeholder="Input Text Here"
          onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
        ></input>
      </form>

      <Button onClick={handleReset}>Reset</Button>
      <Button onClick={sort}>Sort</Button>

      <div>
        <ul>
          {filteredData
            .filter((user) => {
              var dynamicSearch = search;

              if (
                user.name.toLowerCase().includes(dynamicSearch.toLowerCase()) ||
                user.email
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .includes(dynamicSearch.toLowerCase()) ||
                user.phone
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .includes(dynamicSearch.toLowerCase()) ||
                user.address.city
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .includes(dynamicSearch.toLowerCase())
              ) {
                return true;
              }
            })
            .map((val, index) => (
              <li className="li" key={val.id}>
                <p className="list">
                  {"Name: "}
                  {val.name} <br />
                  {"Email: "}
                  {val.email}
                  <br />
                  {"Phone: "}
                  {val.phone}
                  <br />
                  {"City: "}
                  {val.address.city}
                </p>
                <button className="delButton" onClick={() => delItem(val.name)}>
                  x
                </button>
              </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: Add filteredData, setFilteredData to your useEffect Array [filteredData, setFilteredData]

Comment: tried and that did not work, now after I hit sort and search something the map does not even update but I can see that the array updated correctly in my console log.

Thanks though

Comment: I think you need to await getUsers() in your useEffect hook and handleReset() function.

Comment: it did not work unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with this one:

```
  const sort = () => {
    const sortedData = filteredData.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.address.city.localeCompare(b.address.city);
    });
    setFilteredData([...sortedData]);
  };
```

Problem is once you are updating the sorting data in setFilteredData function its not able to observe the changes that needs to be rendered. So always make the copy of the state variables when you are updating the values.